# String split in Java with a date format

Tags: java, string, split

I have the strings as follows:

```
other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco
other data 2 - 2015/11/17, Singapore
```

I want to get San Francisco and Singapore. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you always have the same amount of characters in  other data?

Comment: Is this something you can solve by using substring?

Comment: what is the format? do you have the same set of data?

Comment: I will get the same date format in all the strings.Date format is the same , but other characters may be different in length

Comment: You split by comma and trim the second half if the format is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco
";
String city = s.replace(".* [12][0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, ", "");
```

Comment: Can I use .* [0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}, .Because year may be 1999 also

Comment: Is there any difference between / and \ /

Comment: yes, / has a meaning, so I had to escape it, it has to be \/

Comment: When I use this I am getting an error like invalid sequence

Comment: ah, you might be right, this is java. so there it is :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102617/discussion-between-psr-and-gavriel).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
String sf = "other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco"
String city = sf.substring(27);
```

This is assuming that you're getting each line one at a time and that the format is always the same.

For more information on substring: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

---

***Update:***

I thought you had meant for just those two strings.

Another way you can approach this problem is to use split, which will return an array of Strings for you to choose from.

So the following will work:

```
String sf = "other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco";
String[] chunks = sf.split(',');
String city= chunks[chunks.length - 1].substring(1);
```

The substring is still there because after you split the comma, there will be that extra whitespace that you want to remove.

For more information on split: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Another way you can do this is to incorporate `indexOf()`.

```
String sf = "other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco"
int commaIndex = sf.indexOf(',');
String city = sf.substring(commaIndex + 2);
```

Comment: Except date no other string will have the same no of letters

Comment: Right. So the first character of each city will always be the 27th character of that string. `sf.substring(27) ` will take that first character (for "San Francisco", the "S") all the way till the end of that string.

Comment: But other data 1, other data 2 may not be same length

Comment: @sparky, the strings can be: "foo - 2015/05/06, New York" as well

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you were referring to just these two examples. Let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the city is always the last information in the string, you can use split function

```
string sf="other data 1 - 2015/04/20, San Francisco";
string[] myArray= sf.split(",");
string city= myArray[myArray.length()-1];
```